# Show categories of custom post type and not all posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

I have this page on my website -

It's a custom taxonomy template for a custom post type called Directory Entries with a taxonomy called directory_entry_type which is what's being pulled in here.

At the moment it's just pulling in all the posts under the category "Community Directory" - This category has about 6 children categories that i'd like to pull through on this page but at the moment it's just pulling in all of the posts under community directory.

How can I do this?

This is where I've got to so far -

```
<div id="content" class="col-md-8">



<?php 
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $term_query = $queried_object->term_id;
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );


    query_posts( array(

        'posts_per_page' => -1, // you may edit this number
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'depth'  => 1,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $term_query,
                'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,

                    )
                ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(

                'key' => 'is_member',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
        )
    );



?>


<div class="grid-vw">
    <ul>        

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <li>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">

                <figure class="effect-goliath">
                     <?php 

                        $image = get_field('thumbnail');
                        $size = 'dir-tile'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

                        if( $image ) {

                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

                        }

                    ?>

                    <figcaption>
                        <h2><?php the_title();?> ></h2>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>

        </a>

        </li>


       <?php endwhile; 

            wp_reset_query();
        ?>      </ul>


</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT

So I've solved this with this

```
<div class="grid-vw">
    <ul>        



  <?php
  // List posts by the terms for a custom taxonomy of any post type

  $post_type = 'directory_entry';
  $tax = 'directory_entry_type';
  $tax_args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'parent' => 289
  );
 // get all the first level terms only
  $tax_terms = get_terms( $tax, $tax_args );
  if ($tax_terms) {
  foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { // foreach first level term
  // print the parent heading
    ?>



    <li>

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $tax_term->ID ); ?>">

                <figure class="effect-goliath">
                     <?php 

                        $image = get_field('thumbnail');
                        $size = 'dir-tile'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

                        if( $image ) {

                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

                        }

                    ?>

                    <figcaption>
                        <h2><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?> ></h2>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>

        </a>

           </li>



  <?php wp_reset_query();

  }

  }
  ?>


    </ul>
```

That's pulling in exactly what i want, but now the permalinks aren't working, could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, is your query only pulling posts tagged as the parent category and nothing tagged as a child category? And are you saying you'd like to have everything on this page?

You might try changing `child_of` to `cat` and get rid of `depth`.

But TBH you may want to try a different approach at querying; this question/answer suggests that `query_posts()` is not the best method: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Another approach would be to query for the IDs of the child categories of this parent and then loop through them with individual post queries - if you'd want them in six sections.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using this

```
<div class="grid-vw">
    <ul>        



 <?php
 // List posts by the terms for a custom taxonomy of any post type

 $post_type = 'directory_entry';
 $tax = 'directory_entry_type';
 $tax_args = array(
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'parent' => 289
 );
 // get all the first level terms only
 $tax_terms = get_terms( $tax, $tax_args );
 if ($tax_terms) {
 foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) { // foreach first level term
 // print the parent heading
 ?>



 <li>

 <?php           echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($tax_term).'">';

?>

                <figure class="effect-goliath">
                     <?php 

                        $image = get_field('thumbnail');
                        $size = 'dir-tile'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

                        if( $image ) {

                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

                        }

                    ?>

                    <figcaption>
                        <h2><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?> ></h2>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>

        </a>

        </li>



 <?php wp_reset_query();

 }

 }
 ?>


    </ul>
```